# Add value in column with condition based on other column, getting only last value entered

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to add a value in a column using different condition based on other column. But when doing so, I'm getting only last value that I had entered.

First condition:

```py
df['ProcCodeCat'] = (df['ProcCode'].astype(str).str[:1] == '1')
df['ProcCodeCat'] = df['ProcCodeCat'] .map({True: 'Surgery'})
```

Second condition:

```py
df['ProcCodeCat'] = df['ProcCode'].astype(str).str[:2] == '2'
df['ProcCodeCat'] = df['ProcCodeCat'] .map({True: 'Med'})
```

I am only receiving the output of second condition when I try to execute both at a time in 'ProcCodeCat' column.

Comment: kindly share data, with expected output

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
 def f(x):
   if x.startswith('1'): return 'Surgery'
   elif x.startswith('2'): return 'Med'

df['ProcCodeCat'] = df['ProcCode'].astype(str).apply(f)
```